# sql database non updating

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm totally clueless. When I change anything in the database (Insert, Delete...), changes aren't saved. The changes are visible only, when code is running.

Table is already filled.

I work with .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0.

Sorry for my English.

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SemestralniPrace
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Databaze data = new Databaze(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabazeConnectionString);
            data.Operace("DELETE FROM Pokladna WHERE ID = '1'");
            System.Console.Write(data.Vypis("Select Osoba From Pokladna Where ID='1'"));
            System.Console.ReadKey();          

        }
    }
}
```

Database

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace SemestralniPrace
{
    class Databaze
    {
        SqlCeConnection con;

        public Databaze(string conString)
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
                con.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Console.Write("Chyba databáze-konec aplikace");
                System.Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        public string Vypis(string prikaz)
        {
            string polozka = "";
            using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(prikaz, con))
            {

                SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    polozka = reader.GetString(0);
                }
                return polozka;
            }
        }

        public void Operace(string prikaz)
        {
            SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(prikaz, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code, and as was mentioned already, the connection string.

Comment: On what line are the changes visible and after what line of code are they gone? Are you getting any errors that might cause the database to rollback?

Comment: Please show the connection string. Are you using the shortcut `|DataDirectory|`?

Comment: I edit post and add all code. Any errors or warrings.

Comment: Connection string: Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Databaze.sdf;password=******

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Solution Explorer click on the database file and check the value for the property  `"Copy to Output Directory"`.

I think that you have the value **"Copy Always"** set. You need to change it to **"Copy if newer"**

**EDIT:**
When you look at the data after the DELETE be sure to use a connection pointing to the correct file... :)

Comment: I already have "Copy if newer". I try all options. No change :(

Comment: I ask you again to show your connection string updating your question

Comment: Connection string: Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Databaze.sdf;password=*****

Comment: Check the value for your |DataDirectory| substituition var. Use Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"), I think you will find that it is null. Try also to change the path to the sdf file inserting a specific path like (yourproject)\bin\debug\database.sdf.....

Comment: Yes, it's null. But if I change it to "Data Source=SemestralniPrace/SemestralniPrace/bin/Debug/Databaze.sdf;password=*****" I can't connect to database. Do mean connect string like this?

Comment: That connection string is relative to the point where your program is running. Add the drive or just leave out completely the path (so your sdf file is in the subfolder bin\debug right?)

Comment: And if I change it like and move database+exe to another place, it will not work, right?

Comment: That could be solved if your `Properties.Settings.Default.DatabazeConnectionString` is an application Settings. If so, the current path will be located in your app.config and could be easily changed when installing the app.

Comment: Ok, I add full path and I can connect to database, but it still don't save changes.

Comment: I suppose that Properties.Settings.Default.DatabazeConnectionString is . Because if I move database+exe, it still works.

Comment: Another idea. Is your database column `ID` of string/text datatype?. You are using a string `'1'` to identify the record to delete, not a number.

Comment: It's int and autoincremect.

Comment: And if I use ID=1, no change

Comment: I can't find any other ideas. If you wish you could share the database and your project somewhere and I will try your code.

Comment: I think SQL query isn't trouble. It works. It only don't save change. Any idea?____Ok, thank you.

Comment: Set the permission to download to the file

Comment: Please don't tell me that you are looking the data in your database file through the Server Explorer window using the connection there. That connection points to the file in the project folder not to the one in bin\debug.   You owe me one...... Goodnight

Comment: But if I do System.Console.Write(data.Vypis("Select Osoba From Pokladna Where ID='1'"));
            data.Operace("DELETE FROM Pokladna WHERE ID = 1"); in this order and run exe. After first run, it should write "Já" and after second run "Pavel". Right?

Comment: Or "null". But it still write "Já".

Comment: ID identifies the row with 'Ja', after the delete ID=1 the row no more exists and the search doesn't find anything  and it doesn't write anymore 'Ja'.